# How Test eclipse product using TestComplete..?

Tags: eclipse, testing, testcomplete

I am new for TestComplete
i create a plugin for eclipse .. and now i want to test it using **TestComplete...**
So is there is any example of something..
 Because in case of eclipse the index number of process is also dynamic .. 
so is there is sum plugin or something which make it easy..
Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is comparably hard to work with SWT applications since they contain too many objects without reliable identification properties. For example, all ***Composite*** objects do not differ one from another and the only way to distinguish them is their ***Index*** property. However, this property gets value depending on the creation order of an object and, obviously, can change from run to run.

A good way to work with such applications is using the Name Mapping feature. When working with an ***Eclipse*** application, the most reliable way to map objects is to avoid using indexes and using the ***Required Children*** feature. In this case, to map an object without strong identification properties, you need to find its child or grandchild object that can be identified reliably (e.g. a button with unique caption) and specify it as a required child object. You can find more information on this functionality in the '*Specifying Child Objects Required for Mapped Object Identification*' help topic:
http://smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/12481/

You can also use the ***Extended Find*** feature of the Name Mapping functionality. This feature is similar to the ***FindChild*** method that you can use in scripts. Please find more information on this feature in the '*Using Extended Search Criteria for Mapped Object Identification'* help topic:
http://smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/12466/

BTW, I recommend that you watched the '*Creating Reliable Tests For Dynamic Objects with Name Mapping*' screencast that will help you to understand the Name Mapping functionality better:
http://smartbear.com/support/screencasts/testcomplete/reliable-tests-for-dynamic-objects/

Also, you can ask your questions about ***TestComplete*** in the official forum:
http://smartbear.com/forums/