# TestComplete Integration with Eclipse Project

Tags: java, eclipse, testcomplete

I have an eclipse (java) project that I would like to perform some testing on. It *Looks* like TestComplete may be able to do it, however it's unclear based on what I can find, how exactly to run this testing on an ECLIPSE project.

Do you just open the jar file using TestComplete and so thus using the Eclipse IDE is irrelevant?

Do you have to import the project into TestComplete somehow?

I found this: [How Test eclipse product using TestComplete..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998686/how-test-eclipse-product-using-testcomplete)

Which I would have expected would answer that question, but really doesn't appear to answer the same question I read.

I'm trying assess if I can use this tool to test my software, but I'm a little unclear on how it works with eclipse in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your application in a way whatever you want. After this, TestComplete will be able to work with the application: just record some actions and TestComplete will be able to play them back.

If you need to run the application from TestComplete, you can do this using the Tested Applications feature. It allows running a usual Java application using JAR file as well as running Eclipse as a common exe.